# Multiple MySQL Servers with codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How can I setup my codeigniter application so that if it cant connect to one mysql server it connects to another? ie: set primary mysql and secondary mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would set up multiple codeigniter databases in the config/database (see below)

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'uname';
$db['default']['password'] = 'pword';
$db['default']['database'] = '';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;


$db['db2']['hostname'] = 'hostname1';
$db['db2']['username'] = 'uname';
$db['db2']['password'] = 'pword';
$db['db2']['database'] = '';
$db['db2']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['db2']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['db2']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['db2']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['db2']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['db2']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['db2']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['db2']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['db2']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['db2']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['db2']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Then in my controller I would load the database and check if it was successful.

```
 $this->db = $this->load->database('default', TRUE); //If it isn't pre-loaded 

    if($this->db->conn_id === FALSE){
      $this->db = $this->load->database('db2', TRUE); 
    }
```

I haven't tested it but I would assume it would work.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, that is possible out of the box. You will have to hack the framework.